# how to live update data on localStorage.length()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to update data `localStorage.length` without reload page ?

on event click, `localStorage.SetItem(Item.name, count)`
Then data update it with the function `.text(localStorage.length)`, but data not updated.
thanks

Comment: Please provide us with a https://plnkr.co/edit

Comment: You'll need to provide us with a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry, code here https://embed.plnkr.co/Vd9NuoB6VJJQxPCkHk7m/

Comment: @Arisbagus, What's the problem? When I add items, it shows it at the and when I click reset, it resets it to 0. Seems good to me.

Comment: i need live data `localStorage.length` without refresh page

Comment: oh i'm sorry, in my text editor, i write script in tag `<script> my code </script>` in html body.. and data not updated.

Comment: @Arisbagus I tried this: https://pastebin.com/tTW0j1Sp. And it still worked all good. Everytime I add something to the cart is instantly updates the count, and on reset it goes back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page you load the last `localStorage.length`. But when you reset the cart you do `localStorage.clear();` so you empty the `localStorage`.
In the next line you change the cart text: `$('#cart_total').text('(' + storageCount + ')');` and you load the variable `storageCount`, but the problem is that you never updated that variable.

Use this:

```
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
   localStorage.clear();
   $('#cart_total').text('(' + localStorage.length + ')');
});
```